# What does retain as property attribute exactly do in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

If I declare a public property as :

```
@property (retain) NSString * name;
```

Then how does the compiler implicitly implement this? I have read that the retain gains ownership over the instance variable "_name". I have also read that "retain" message increases the reference count of the object.
So each time I call the setter for "name" property in the above example, will it increase the reference count?

So after this,

```
object.name=@"name1";
object.name=@"name2";
```

Will the reference count be 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255861/property-and-retain-assign-copy-nonatomic-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

According to Blamdarot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855536):

> "retain" is needed when the attribute is a pointer to an object. The setter generated by @synthesize will retain (aka add a retain count) the object. You will need to release the object when you are finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question:

```
object.name = @"name1";
```

`name` now holds a strong reference to the "name1" string instance.

```
object.name = @"name2";
```

`name` now holds a strong reference to the "name2" string instance. No object holds a reference to the "name1" instance, and a release statement will be inserted by the compiler for "name1". (in practice, the first statement will likely be optimized away entirely).