# Objective-C - Call a method that modify a textField from another class

Tags: objective-c, methods, nstextfield

I have two questions :

- When I try to call a method from different class (this method modify a textfield after having checked a condition) the method is well called (the NSLog in statutInternet works) but the TextField isn't modified..
  When I do it from the (IBAction)internet method it works .. Any solution ?
- Why Xcode want me to called my variables (like internetTextfield) with a _ before it ?

WindowsController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WindowController : NSWindowController
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *internetLabel;

- (void)statutInternet;
- (IBAction)internet:(id)sender;

@end
```

WindowsController.m :

```
#import "WindowController.h"
@implementation WindowController

- (IBAction)internet:(id)sender;
{
   [self statutInternet];
}

- (void)statutInternet;
{
    NSLog(@"Callfunctionworks");
    if (condition) {
    [_internetLabel setStringValue:@"TxtFieldWorks!"];
    }

}
```

I try to call the method statutInternet with this from another class :

```
WindowController *fenetre = [[WindowController alloc] init];
[fenetre statutInternet];
```

Answer (score 1):

> **When I try to call a method from different class it doesn't work:**

That's because, You're making another `WindowController` instance using this code:

```
WindowController *fenetre = [[WindowController alloc] init];
```

This is another new separate instance of same class, which I guess you're not showing. So you want to take reference to the window that's already showing rather than making a new instance.

> **Why Xcode want me to called my variables (like internetTextfield) with a _ before it ?**

That's because when you declare variable using `@property` it does three things:

1. Makes an internal variable by adding the conventional underscore (_) to the start of the variable name. That's why you've `_` as prefix of your variable.
2. Makes a setter-getter methods.
3. Takes the keywords you used (ie. assign, strong, weak) in account while implementing the setter-getters.

You can read a good discussion here: [@property and retain, assign, copy, nonatomic in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255861/593709)

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't know .. how can I call the existing instance without creating a new one ?

Comment: Actually you need to know where in your app you're first creating this instance, may be your app delegate?

Comment: Yes I think, (I started from an existing project : ASHStatusItemPopover https://github.com/adamhartford/ASHStatusItemPopover ) here is what I have in the AppDelegate :                                           ASHStatusItemPopover *statusItemPopover = [[ASHStatusItemPopover alloc] init];                                                      statusItemPopover.windowController = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WindowController"];

Comment: You need to have this reference in your other class.

Answer (score 0):

The NSTextField (and all of the other UI items) is not created yet when you call statutInternet method.

When your window loaded, your views will be ready :

```
_fenetre = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WindowController"];
[_fenetre showWindow:_fenetre.window];
[_fenetre statutInternet];
```