# insert text from textview to string return NSMallocBlock in the string objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have a textview that user can edit, when I try to insert the text from the textview to a local property from type Nsstring, I got in this property NSMallocBlock. what is the reason? thank you!
this is the defintaion of cartItemComment:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString * cartItemComment;
```

and this is the code:

```
CartItem *cartItem = [[CartItem alloc]init];
cartItem.cartItemComment = itemRequestText.text;
```

cartitem is a object that have a property cartItemComment, after those lines, I got NSMallocBlock in cartItemComment.

[another problem, i can get a weird string like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MTeA.png)

Comment: Cant help without code. Please add your code here

Comment: I added more info. does it understand now?

Comment: No. `itemRequestText.text` is nil? Could you show the definition of `cartItemComment`. Is it a property ? strong and nonatomic? (if you put assign, clearly that could crash). Also, it a NSString property ? Could you show the stack trace of the crash ? The whole error message?

Comment: this is not a crash, but after, when i try to use this cartItemComment it is failed.

Comment: the cartItemComment is not nil, it just get a weird type as NSMallocBlock

Comment: What do you think is weird about the image you linked?  The variable is a string pointer (NSString *) and it has an address.

Comment: usually you can see the string when you look on it

Comment: Try changing `assign` to `strong`.

Comment: Thanx!!! looks good! what is the different?

Comment: @yoc: I previously said "(if you put assign, clearly that could crash)". Didn't you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255861/property-and-retain-assign-copy-nonatomic-in-objective-c assign is generally used for non-object (primitive) properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assign` property attribute applies to primitive types, it does nothing with the object reference. When an object is assigned to this property, it is deallocated (if it is not retained by some other object), and all you have left is a pointer to the memory where it once was. Never use `assign` to store objects.

`weak` is similar to `assign`, with the only difference that when the object referenced by this property is deallocated (retain count reaches zero), it is set to `nil`, so you would never have a pointer to garbage memory.

`strong` retains the object and prevents it from being deallocated.

Your property should be declared like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cartItemComment;
```

Comment: Thanx pckill!! you are really helped me!!