# class and extending interface in objective c

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode

I know bit of ts and I am new to Objective C.

I have a meeting param which I want to extend in meeting obj (MeetingConfig.h) file

```
@interface MeetingParams : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* roomName;
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* authToken;
  @property (nonatomic, assign)Boolean autoTune;
  @property (nonatomic, assign)NSString* apiBase;
  @property (nonatomic, assign)Boolean showSetupScreen;
@end

@interface MeetingConfig : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* roomName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* authToken;
@property (nonatomic, assign)Boolean autoTune;
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSString* apiBase;
@property (nonatomic, assign)Boolean showSetupScreen;

- (void) setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken;
- (void) setApiBase:(NSString *)apiBase;
- (void) setShowSetupScreen:(Boolean)showSetupScreen;
- (void) setAutoTuneEnabled:(Boolean)autoTune;
- (id) init;
@end
```

How can I do that? (right now I know there is redundant code)

Also, I know I am mixing language but can someone tell me what would be the equivalence of this code from Java in objective C?

```
 MeetingConfig config = new MeetingConfig();
        config.setRoomName("abc");
```

For now, I have made this as `MeetingConfig.m` file

```
#import "MeetingConfig.h"

@implementation MeetingConfig

- (id) init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.apiBase = @"https://api.xyz.in";
    self.showSetupScreen = false;
    self.autoTune = true;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken
{
  self.authToken = authToken;
}
- (void) setApiBase:(NSString *)apiBase
{
  self.apiBase = apiBase;
}
- (void) setShowSetupScreen:(Boolean)showSetupScreen
{
  self.showSetupScreen = showSetupScreen;
}
- (void) setAutoTuneEnabled:(Boolean)autoTune
{
  self.autoTune = autoTune;
}

@end
```

Which I am hoping is equivalent to my this file

```
package com.dyteclientmobile;

public class MeetingConfig {
    public String roomName;
    public String authToken;
    public boolean autoTune;
    public String apiBase;
    public boolean showSetupScreen;

    public MeetingConfig() {
        this.apiBase = "https://api.xyz.in";
        this.showSetupScreen = false;
        this.autoTune = true;
    }

    public MeetingConfig setRoomName(String roomName) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
        return this;
    }

    public MeetingConfig setAuthToken(String authToken) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
        return this;
    }

    public MeetingConfig setApiBase(String apiBase) {
        this.apiBase = apiBase;
        return this;
    }

    public MeetingConfig setShowSetupScreen(boolean showSetupScreen) {
        this.showSetupScreen = showSetupScreen;
        return this;
    }

    public MeetingConfig setAutoTuneEnabled(boolean autoTune) {
        this.autoTune = autoTune;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: MeetingConfig and MeetingParams seems the same, it look like one will do the job. and, the setter method will be created by default if no special usage.so I guess just keep MeetingConfig, and remove the setter method, it seems more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the `MeetingConfig` definition, you can do something like, in `MeetingConfig.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MeetingConfig : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *roomName;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *authToken;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL autoTune;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *apiBase;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL showSetupScreen;

- (id)init;
- (MeetingConfig *)setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken;
- (MeetingConfig *)setRoomName:(NSString *)roomName;
- (MeetingConfig *)setApiBase:(NSString *)apiBase;
- (MeetingConfig *)setShowSetupScreen:(BOOL)showSetupScreen;
- (MeetingConfig *)setAutoTuneEnabled:(BOOL)autoTune;

@end
```

and, in `MeetingConfig.m`:

```
#import "MeetingConfig.h"

@implementation MeetingConfig

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _apiBase = @"https://api.xyz.in";
    _showSetupScreen = false;
    _autoTune = true;
  }
  return self;
}

- (MeetingConfig *)setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken {
  _authToken = authToken;
  return self;
}

- (MeetingConfig *)setRoomName:(NSString *)roomName {
  _roomName = roomName;
  return self;
}

- (MeetingConfig *)setApiBase:(NSString *)apiBase {
  _apiBase = apiBase;
  return self;
}

- (MeetingConfig *)setShowSetupScreen:(BOOL)showSetupScreen {
  _showSetupScreen = showSetupScreen;
  return self;
}

- (MeetingConfig *)setAutoTuneEnabled:(BOOL)autoTune {
  _autoTune = autoTune;
  return self;
}

@end
```

Finally, an example of using this:

```
#import "MeetingConfig.h"

void printConfig(MeetingConfig *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MeetingConfig *config = [[MeetingConfig alloc] init];
  printConfig(config);
  [[[config setRoomName:@"abc"] setAuthToken:@"def"] setApiBase:@"http://localhost:8080"];
  printConfig(config);
}

void printConfig(MeetingConfig *config) {
  printf("roomName:         %s\n", [config.roomName UTF8String]);
  printf("authToken:        %s\n", [config.authToken UTF8String]);
  printf("autoTone:         %d\n", config.autoTune);
  printf("apiBase:          %s\n", [config.apiBase UTF8String]);
  printf("showSetupScreen:  %d\n", config.showSetupScreen);
}
```

The important differences between this and what you had put together:

- Addition of the `readonly` attribute to each property, to ensure the corresponding `set*` methods weren't synthesised, as they would conflict with the fluent versions
- Modification to `init` and setters to update the instance variables directly
- Changing the signature and implementation of each setter method to return a pointer to `self`, making them fluent

You'll need to take a look a the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for `@property`, and [other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255861/property-retain-assign-copy-nonatomic-in-objective-c) to get a sense of which attributes need to be set, I don't have enough experience to be absolutely sure on that front.